# Javascript content change but stay in same location

Tags: javascript, jquery

This problem is a little difficult to explain but here goes. I have different programming language examples on my page. The different examples show you how to "create a car", "delete a car", "update a car"... Each of these examples have a tab to switch from a php example to a curl example.

The problem is when switching tab to show a different language, the length of the content changes so you end up in a different location of the page.

How can I keep the user viewing the same example when switching tabs?

```
$(".create_car_example").change(function(){
    $(".create_code").removeClass("selected");
    $(".create_code_" + $(this).val().toLowerCase()).addClass("selected");
    //$(this).val() <-- changes to either 'php' or 'curl'
});
```

Comment: I believe it would be a good idea to show the code changing the hash.

Comment: @JeremyThille Sorry, I've just rewrote my question, I am using `window.location.hash` on the same page but for a different reason.

Comment: Hmmm... Yet, it is a bit difficult to imagine. I don't understand "you end up in a different location of the page". Do you mean the page scrolls down when you click a tab, and that's what you want to avoid?

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, the page scrolls and results in me seeing a different part of the page.

Comment: Okay. So the actual question is : why is the page scrolling when it should not? Did you put anchors? What's the HTML code for the tabs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".create_car_example").change(function(){

    var pre_top = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    $(".create_code").removeClass("selected");
    $(".create_code_" + $(this).val().toLowerCase()).addClass("selected");
    //$(this).val() <-- changes to either 'php' or 'curl'

    var post_top = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if(pre_top > post_top){
        var diff_top = pre_top - post_top;
        new_top = window.scrollY - diff_top;
    }

    if(pre_top < post_top){
        var diff_top = post_top - pre_top;
        var new_top = window.scrollY + diff_top;
    }

        window.scrollTo(0, new_top);

});
```